# Java GregorianCalendar check if a day is between other two

Tags: java, date, between

Let's say I have two GregorianCalendar dates with the year, the month and the day from the month and they give me another GregorianCalendar date.

Is there a defined method to check if the given date is between the other two dates?

If not, would I need to start comparing the years, then the months and finally the day?

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of many other questions.

Quick answer: avoid the old date-time classes and use only java.time classes.

Convert to `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime();
```

Extract a date-only value.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

Compare with other `LocalDate` objects by calling methods: compareTo, equals, isBefore, and isAfter.

Tip: search Stack Overflow for "Half-Open".

Tip: `! isBefore` is a shorter way of saying "is equal to OR later than".